.NET MAUI unable to execute EF migration
I have a .NET MAUI app, that I want to run on Windows. App is starting without errors, the AppDbContext got injected. But when I tried to execute my first migration I got the following error:
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type 'RuntimeType'. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[Solution.DataBase.AppDbContext]' while attempting to activate 'Solution.DataBase.AppDbContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
I tried the migration from the console with the EF CLI, I got the same result.
My EF project is in a class library. Here is how I configured my NET MAUI project.
//MuiProgram.cs
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder.UseMauiApp<App>()
               .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
               .UseMauiCommunityToolkitMarkup()
               .UseFontConfiguration()
               .UseAppConfigurations()
               .UseAppSettingsMapping()
               .UseDIConfiguration()
               .UseMsSqlServer();

#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }
}

//extension to configre the EF
public static class ConfigureSQLServer
{
    public static MauiAppBuilder UseMsSqlServer(this MauiAppBuilder builder)
    {   
        string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetRequiredSection("SqlConnectionString").Get<string>();

        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(connectionString);

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
        );

        return builder;
    }
}

//AppDbContext
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MovieEntity> Movies { get; set; }

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}

I tried everything that I could google it out, but nothing solved my problem.
Any idea?
thnx
